# Is there a MTG card similar (either in image or name) to R2D2 for a Star Wars theme deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm putting together a theme deck and I've already selected the following:

- Nephalia Smuggler
- Sylvan Yeti
- Black Knight
- Brass Man

There are several candidate cards for Leia or Luke or even light sabers, but I'm unfamiliar with the newer sets, and can't think of anything that even remotely resembles R2D2.

Is there such a card?

Comment: I asked Mark Rosewater for input on his blog. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Tumblr to know when my questions get answers. http://markrosewater.tumblr.com/

Comment: I found a popular deck called Naya Lightsaber, but I don't see any card that looks like a lightsabre :-/

Comment: I was thinking Sword of Fire and Ice for that one. Brass Man doesn't exactly look like a protocol droid, truth told...

Comment: Soldevi Sentry sort of looks like a protocol droid: http://magiccards.info/ai/en/176.html and http://magiccards.info/ai/en/175.html.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Mindless Automaton](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mindless%20Automaton) looks a bit like R2D2

Comment: That's actually pretty good... the picture and the name almost work. If only there were a Lando Calrissian... ;)

Comment: Older art for Triskelion (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=2077) looks a lot like Mindless Automaton as well